# Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor

Tags: spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x

During Springboot 3 and hibernate6 migration, during application startup facing below error
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor@38ffba03`
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:364)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor@38ffba03`
at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadHelper.resolveArrayJdbcMapping(MultiKeyLoadHelper.java:46)
at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.(MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildMultiIdLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:892)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3420)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
... 20 common frames omitted

Tried by adding below dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

anything else need to be added?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60:2.21.1 with

'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.7.3' worked for me.

Ref-: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/698

we have to completely remove this com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60:2.21.1 and use io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating to [hypersistence-utils](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils). It's the successor of `hibernate-types` and fixed a similar issue for me.